# Have a group for 'null' elements

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I have a set of objects, with a parameter that may or may not be defined.

I am trying to group those using LINQ.

I am using the following syntax:

```
(From o In oList Group By Category = o.sCategory Into CategoryGroup = Group)
```

It works fine, however, the objects with no `sCategory` property are not returned.

I would like to achieve the same thing, but with an additional group for those objects.

I have found a similar question ([Linq GroupBy with each null value as a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28760827/linq-groupby-with-each-null-value-as-a-group)), but it uses the method syntax, and I would like to stick with the query syntax, as I think it is more readable.

My attempts at converting it, such as:

```
(From o In oList Group By Category = (Function (p) IIf(p.sCategory Is Nothing,"Empty", p.sCategory)) Into CategoryGroup = Group)
```

did not work: I returns a single group, with all objects, and the name `'<generated method>'`

How would you achieve this?

Comment: _"did not help me very much"_ but a little bit, say 90%? Just kidding, please tell us what's not working otherwise its difficult to help. **Edit** Your fix _"did not work."_ isn't better

Comment: I have edited to reflect my failure :)
I returns a single group, with all objects, and the name '<generated method>'

Comment: edit your question to include this, don't comment it

Comment: Learn fluent(method) syntax. It makes LINQ queries easier to write and understand. And not all functions are available in query syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I always use LINQ in method syntax. I tried to do it in query syntax, but somehow it does not know `Group By`.

If I do it using method syntax, the function works

```
class MyObject
{
   string Category {get; set;}
   string Value {get; set;}
}

IEnumerable<MyObject> myObjects = new List<MyObject>
{
    new MyObject() {Category = "A", Value = "A1"},
    new MyObject() {Category = "A", Value = "A2"},
    new MyObject() {Category = "B", Value = "B1"},
    new MyObject() {Category = null, Value = "empty"},
    new MyObject() {Category = null, Value = "nothing"},
}
var groups = myObjects.GroupBy(myObject => myObject.Category);
```

The result is a sequence with three groups:
 - a group with Key = "A", group members the objects with "A1" and "A2",
 - a group with Key = "B", group members the object with "B1",
 - a group with Key = null, group memebers the objects with "empty" and "nothing"

So I think that either there is no `Group By` in query syntax, or this `Group By` does not work as you expect.

Consider using the method syntax.